# Sorting data on y-axis using ggplot

Tags: r, sorting, ggplot2, facet

First off this is my first post so go easy. Also thank you for any input in advance. I am trying to plot the following but the data on the x and y-axis are completely out of order.

I have looked through several posts about `reorder()` but I cant seem to apply it correctly. Also since I am a new member I can't included a picture of the graph so I hope the issue is clear.

```
carb_data<-read.csv("Carb_Insulin_BG.csv", header=TRUE)

data1<-subset(carb_data,Subject.ID..==20)

carb1<-subset(data1, Visit == 1)

library(ggplot2)

q<- ggplot(data=carb1, aes(x=Start, y=Amount, group=Type, color= Type) + geom_point() + geom_line() 
+ theme(text = element_text(size=8), axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, vjust=1))
r<- q + facet_grid(Sort~., scales=free)

print(r)
```

[image]
Here is what the data looks like. I am just interested in plotting `Time` (x-axis) and `Amount` (y-axis). The x-axis should be ordered from the earliest (9:54) to latest (16:27) and the the y-axis should be ordered from lowest (4) ascending to the highest (128). Here is the data:

```
    > dput(carb1)
structure(list(EDC.ID. = structure(c(28L, 28L, 8L, 28L, 28L, 
28L, 8L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 8L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 
28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 8L, 28L, 28L), .Label = c("Subject 1", 
"Subject 10", "Subject 11", "Subject 12", "Subject 13", "Subject 14", 
"Subject 15", "Subject 16", "Subject 17", "Subject 18", "Subject 19", 
"Subject 2", "Subject 20", "Subject 3", "Subject 4", "Subject 5", 
"Subject 6", "Subject 7", "Subject 8", "Subject 9", "SUBJECT1", 
"SUBJECT10", "SUBJECT11", "SUBJECT12", "SUBJECT13", "SUBJECT14", 
"SUBJECT15", "SUBJECT16", "SUBJECT17", "SUBJECT18", "SUBJECT19", 
"SUBJECT2", "SUBJECT20", "SUBJECT3", "SUBJECT4", "SUBJECT5", 
"SUBJECT6", "SUBJECT7", "SUBJECT8", "SUBJECT9"), class = "factor"), 
    Subject.ID.. = c(20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
    20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
    20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L), Visit = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Data = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 19L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 19L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 19L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 19L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("-", 
    "10/1/14", "10/3/14", "10/7/14", "8/14/14", "8/18/14", "8/19/14", 
    "8/20/14", "8/21/14", "8/25/14", "8/27/14", "8/28/14", "9/1/14", 
    "9/10/14", "9/12/14", "9/15/14", "9/16/14", "9/18/14", "9/19/14", 
    "9/2/14", "9/22/14", "9/23/14", "9/24/14", "9/25/14", "9/26/14", 
    "9/29/14", "9/3/14", "9/30/14", "9/4/14", "9/5/14", "9/8/14", 
    "9/9/14"), class = "factor"), Start = structure(c(528L, 13L, 
    14L, 33L, 48L, 62L, 70L, 83L, 97L, 112L, 126L, 140L, 152L, 
    155L, 175L, 194L, 208L, 221L, 236L, 249L, 263L, 313L, 328L, 
    343L, 354L, 358L, 374L), .Label = c("0:00", "0:16", "1:25", 
    "10:00", "10:01", "10:02", "10:03", "10:04", "10:05", "10:06", 
    "10:07", "10:08", "10:09", "10:10", "10:11", "10:12", "10:13", 
    "10:14", "10:15", "10:16", "10:17", "10:18", "10:19", "10:20", 
    "10:21", "10:22", "10:23", "10:24", "10:25", "10:27", "10:28", 
    "10:29", "10:30", "10:31", "10:32", "10:33", "10:34", "10:35", 
    "10:36", "10:37", "10:38", "10:39", "10:40", "10:41", "10:42", 
    "10:43", "10:44", "10:45", "10:46", "10:47", "10:48", "10:49", 
    "10:50", "10:51", "10:52", "10:53", "10:54", "10:55", "10:57", 
    "10:58", "10:59", "11:00", "11:01", "11:03", "11:04", "11:05", 
    "11:06", "11:07", "11:08", "11:09", "11:10", "11:12", "11:13", 
    "11:14", "11:15", "11:16", "11:17", "11:18", "11:19", "11:20", 
    "11:21", "11:22", "11:23", "11:24", "11:25", "11:26", "11:27", 
    "11:28", "11:29", "11:30", "11:31", "11:33", "11:34", "11:35", 
    "11:36", "11:37", "11:38", "11:39", "11:40", "11:41", "11:42", 
    "11:43", "11:44", "11:45", "11:46", "11:47", "11:48", "11:49", 
    "11:50", "11:51", "11:52", "11:53", "11:54", "11:55", "11:56", 
    "11:57", "11:58", "11:59", "12:00", "12:01", "12:03", "12:04", 
    "12:05", "12:06", "12:07", "12:08", "12:09", "12:10", "12:11", 
    "12:12", "12:13", "12:14", "12:15", "12:16", "12:18", "12:19", 
    "12:20", "12:21", "12:22", "12:23", "12:24", "12:25", "12:26", 
    "12:27", "12:28", "12:29", "12:30", "12:31", "12:32", "12:33", 
    "12:34", "12:35", "12:36", "12:37", "12:38", "12:39", "12:40", 
    "12:41", "12:42", "12:43", "12:44", "12:45", "12:46", "12:47", 
    "12:48", "12:49", "12:50", "12:51", "12:52", "12:53", "12:54", 
    "12:55", "12:56", "12:57", "12:58", "12:59", "13:00", "13:01", 
    "13:03", "13:04", "13:05", "13:06", "13:07", "13:08", "13:09", 
    "13:10", "13:11", "13:12", "13:13", "13:14", "13:15", "13:16", 
    "13:17", "13:18", "13:19", "13:20", "13:21", "13:22", "13:23", 
    "13:24", "13:25", "13:27", "13:28", "13:29", "13:30", "13:31", 
    "13:32", "13:33", "13:34", "13:35", "13:36", "13:37", "13:38", 
    "13:39", "13:40", "13:42", "13:44", "13:45", "13:46", "13:47", 
    "13:48", "13:49", "13:50", "13:51", "13:52", "13:53", "13:54", 
    "13:55", "13:56", "13:57", "13:58", "13:59", "14:00", "14:01", 
    "14:02", "14:03", "14:04", "14:05", "14:06", "14:08", "14:09", 
    "14:10", "14:11", "14:12", "14:14", "14:15", "14:16", "14:17", 
    "14:18", "14:19", "14:20", "14:21", "14:22", "14:23", "14:24", 
    "14:25", "14:26", "14:27", "14:28", "14:29", "14:30", "14:31", 
    "14:33", "14:34", "14:35", "14:36", "14:37", "14:38", "14:39", 
    "14:40", "14:41", "14:42", "14:43", "14:44", "14:45", "14:46", 
    "14:48", "14:49", "14:50", "14:51", "14:52", "14:53", "14:54", 
    "14:55", "14:57", "14:58", "14:59", "15:00", "15:01", "15:02", 
    "15:03", "15:04", "15:05", "15:06", "15:07", "15:08", "15:09", 
    "15:10", "15:12", "15:13", "15:14", "15:15", "15:16", "15:17", 
    "15:18", "15:19", "15:20", "15:21", "15:22", "15:23", "15:24", 
    "15:25", "15:26", "15:27", "15:28", "15:29", "15:30", "15:31", 
    "15:32", "15:33", "15:34", "15:35", "15:36", "15:37", "15:38", 
    "15:39", "15:40", "15:41", "15:42", "15:43", "15:44", "15:45", 
    "15:46", "15:47", "15:48", "15:49", "15:50", "15:51", "15:52", 
    "15:53", "15:54", "15:55", "15:56", "15:57", "15:58", "15:59", 
    "16:00", "16:01", "16:02", "16:03", "16:04", "16:05", "16:06", 
    "16:07", "16:08", "16:09", "16:10", "16:11", "16:12", "16:13", 
    "16:14", "16:15", "16:16", "16:17", "16:18", "16:19", "16:20", 
    "16:21", "16:22", "16:23", "16:24", "16:25", "16:26", "16:27", 
    "16:28", "16:29", "16:30", "16:31", "16:32", "16:33", "16:34", 
    "16:35", "16:36", "16:37", "16:38", "16:39", "16:40", "16:42", 
    "16:43", "16:44", "16:45", "16:46", "16:47", "16:48", "16:49", 
    "16:50", "16:51", "16:52", "16:53", "16:54", "16:55", "16:56", 
    "16:57", "16:58", "16:59", "17:00", "17:01", "17:02", "17:03", 
    "17:04", "17:05", "17:06", "17:07", "17:08", "17:09", "17:10", 
    "17:11", "17:12", "17:14", "17:15", "17:17", "17:18", "17:19", 
    "17:20", "17:21", "17:22", "17:23", "17:24", "17:25", "17:26", 
    "17:29", "17:30", "17:32", "17:34", "17:35", "17:36", "17:38", 
    "17:39", "17:40", "17:45", "17:50", "17:51", "17:54", "18:09", 
    "18:15", "2:40", "21:24", "21:27", "21:39", "3:48", "7:51", 
    "8:00", "8:04", "8:05", "8:10", "8:14", "8:15", "8:18", "8:26", 
    "8:29", "8:31", "8:33", "8:37", "8:39", "8:40", "8:41", "8:43", 
    "8:44", "8:45", "8:47", "8:48", "8:50", "8:51", "8:52", "8:54", 
    "8:55", "8:57", "8:58", "8:59", "9:00", "9:01", "9:02", "9:03", 
    "9:04", "9:05", "9:06", "9:07", "9:08", "9:09", "9:11", "9:12", 
    "9:13", "9:14", "9:15", "9:17", "9:18", "9:19", "9:20", "9:21", 
    "9:22", "9:23", "9:24", "9:25", "9:27", "9:28", "9:30", "9:32", 
    "9:33", "9:34", "9:35", "9:36", "9:37", "9:38", "9:39", "9:40", 
    "9:42", "9:43", "9:44", "9:45", "9:46", "9:47", "9:48", "9:49", 
    "9:50", "9:51", "9:52", "9:53", "9:54", "9:55", "9:56", "9:57", 
    "9:58", "9:59"), class = "factor"), End = structure(c(529L, 
    13L, 14L, 33L, 48L, 62L, 70L, 83L, 97L, 112L, 126L, 140L, 
    154L, 155L, 175L, 194L, 208L, 221L, 236L, 249L, 263L, 313L, 
    328L, 343L, 174L, 358L, 374L), .Label = c("0:00", "0:16", 
    "1:25", "10:00", "10:01", "10:02", "10:03", "10:04", "10:05", 
    "10:06", "10:07", "10:08", "10:09", "10:10", "10:11", "10:12", 
    "10:13", "10:14", "10:15", "10:16", "10:17", "10:18", "10:19", 
    "10:20", "10:21", "10:22", "10:23", "10:24", "10:25", "10:27", 
    "10:28", "10:29", "10:30", "10:31", "10:32", "10:33", "10:34", 
    "10:35", "10:36", "10:37", "10:38", "10:39", "10:40", "10:41", 
    "10:42", "10:43", "10:44", "10:45", "10:46", "10:47", "10:48", 
    "10:49", "10:50", "10:51", "10:52", "10:53", "10:54", "10:55", 
    "10:57", "10:58", "10:59", "11:00", "11:01", "11:03", "11:04", 
    "11:05", "11:06", "11:07", "11:08", "11:09", "11:10", "11:12", 
    "11:13", "11:14", "11:15", "11:16", "11:17", "11:18", "11:19", 
    "11:20", "11:21", "11:22", "11:23", "11:24", "11:25", "11:26", 
    "11:27", "11:28", "11:29", "11:30", "11:31", "11:33", "11:34", 
    "11:35", "11:36", "11:37", "11:38", "11:39", "11:40", "11:41", 
    "11:42", "11:43", "11:44", "11:45", "11:46", "11:47", "11:48", 
    "11:49", "11:50", "11:51", "11:52", "11:53", "11:54", "11:55", 
    "11:56", "11:57", "11:58", "11:59", "12:00", "12:01", "12:03", 
    "12:04", "12:05", "12:06", "12:07", "12:08", "12:09", "12:10", 
    "12:11", "12:12", "12:13", "12:14", "12:15", "12:16", "12:18", 
    "12:19", "12:20", "12:21", "12:22", "12:23", "12:24", "12:25", 
    "12:26", "12:27", "12:28", "12:29", "12:30", "12:31", "12:32", 
    "12:33", "12:34", "12:35", "12:36", "12:37", "12:38", "12:39", 
    "12:40", "12:41", "12:42", "12:43", "12:44", "12:45", "12:46", 
    "12:47", "12:48", "12:49", "12:50", "12:51", "12:52", "12:53", 
    "12:54", "12:55", "12:56", "12:57", "12:58", "12:59", "13:00", 
    "13:01", "13:03", "13:04", "13:05", "13:06", "13:07", "13:08", 
    "13:09", "13:10", "13:11", "13:12", "13:13", "13:14", "13:15", 
    "13:16", "13:17", "13:18", "13:19", "13:20", "13:21", "13:22", 
    "13:23", "13:24", "13:25", "13:27", "13:28", "13:29", "13:30", 
    "13:31", "13:32", "13:33", "13:34", "13:35", "13:36", "13:37", 
    "13:38", "13:39", "13:40", "13:41", "13:42", "13:44", "13:45", 
    "13:46", "13:48", "13:49", "13:50", "13:51", "13:52", "13:53", 
    "13:54", "13:55", "13:56", "13:57", "13:58", "13:59", "14:00", 
    "14:01", "14:02", "14:03", "14:04", "14:05", "14:06", "14:08", 
    "14:09", "14:10", "14:11", "14:12", "14:14", "14:15", "14:16", 
    "14:17", "14:18", "14:19", "14:20", "14:21", "14:22", "14:23", 
    "14:24", "14:25", "14:26", "14:27", "14:28", "14:29", "14:30", 
    "14:31", "14:33", "14:34", "14:35", "14:36", "14:37", "14:38", 
    "14:39", "14:40", "14:41", "14:42", "14:43", "14:44", "14:45", 
    "14:46", "14:48", "14:49", "14:50", "14:51", "14:52", "14:53", 
    "14:54", "14:55", "14:57", "14:58", "14:59", "15:00", "15:01", 
    "15:02", "15:03", "15:04", "15:05", "15:06", "15:07", "15:08", 
    "15:09", "15:10", "15:12", "15:13", "15:14", "15:15", "15:16", 
    "15:17", "15:18", "15:19", "15:20", "15:21", "15:22", "15:23", 
    "15:24", "15:25", "15:26", "15:27", "15:28", "15:29", "15:30", 
    "15:31", "15:32", "15:33", "15:34", "15:35", "15:36", "15:37", 
    "15:38", "15:39", "15:40", "15:41", "15:42", "15:43", "15:44", 
    "15:45", "15:46", "15:47", "15:48", "15:49", "15:50", "15:51", 
    "15:52", "15:53", "15:54", "15:55", "15:56", "15:57", "15:58", 
    "15:59", "16:00", "16:01", "16:02", "16:03", "16:04", "16:05", 
    "16:06", "16:07", "16:08", "16:09", "16:10", "16:11", "16:12", 
    "16:13", "16:14", "16:15", "16:16", "16:17", "16:18", "16:19", 
    "16:20", "16:21", "16:22", "16:23", "16:24", "16:25", "16:26", 
    "16:27", "16:28", "16:29", "16:30", "16:31", "16:32", "16:33", 
    "16:34", "16:35", "16:36", "16:37", "16:38", "16:39", "16:40", 
    "16:42", "16:43", "16:44", "16:45", "16:46", "16:47", "16:48", 
    "16:49", "16:50", "16:51", "16:52", "16:53", "16:54", "16:55", 
    "16:56", "16:57", "16:58", "16:59", "17:00", "17:01", "17:02", 
    "17:03", "17:04", "17:05", "17:06", "17:07", "17:08", "17:09", 
    "17:10", "17:11", "17:12", "17:14", "17:15", "17:17", "17:18", 
    "17:19", "17:20", "17:21", "17:22", "17:23", "17:24", "17:25", 
    "17:26", "17:29", "17:30", "17:32", "17:34", "17:35", "17:36", 
    "17:38", "17:39", "17:40", "17:45", "17:50", "17:51", "17:54", 
    "18:00", "18:09", "18:15", "2:40", "21:24", "21:27", "21:39", 
    "3:48", "7:51", "8:00", "8:04", "8:05", "8:10", "8:14", "8:15", 
    "8:18", "8:26", "8:29", "8:31", "8:33", "8:37", "8:39", "8:40", 
    "8:41", "8:43", "8:44", "8:45", "8:47", "8:48", "8:50", "8:51", 
    "8:52", "8:54", "8:55", "8:57", "8:58", "8:59", "9:00", "9:01", 
    "9:02", "9:03", "9:04", "9:05", "9:06", "9:07", "9:08", "9:09", 
    "9:11", "9:12", "9:13", "9:14", "9:15", "9:17", "9:18", "9:19", 
    "9:20", "9:21", "9:22", "9:23", "9:24", "9:25", "9:27", "9:28", 
    "9:30", "9:32", "9:33", "9:34", "9:35", "9:36", "9:37", "9:38", 
    "9:39", "9:40", "9:42", "9:43", "9:44", "9:45", "9:46", "9:47", 
    "9:48", "9:49", "9:50", "9:51", "9:52", "9:53", "9:54", "9:55", 
    "9:56", "9:57", "9:58", "9:59"), class = "factor"), Type = structure(c(16L, 
    16L, 14L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 5L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 4L, 
    16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 4L, 
    16L, 16L), .Label = c("BGM", "Dextrose 50%", "dextrose Tabs", 
    "Food or Drink", "Humalog (units)", "Humalog sc (units)", 
    "Humalog SC (units)", "Injection (ccs)", "IV Dextrose(mL)", 
    "Lantus (units)", "Levemir (units)", "Novolin R (units)", 
    "Novolin R IV (units)", "Oral", "Other", "YSI"), class = "factor"), 
    Amount = structure(c(657L, 643L, 448L, 777L, 687L, 637L, 
    448L, 616L, 595L, 530L, 508L, 512L, 23L, 561L, 733L, 34L, 
    63L, 53L, 76L, 71L, 38L, 652L, 703L, 635L, 434L, 646L, 667L
    ), .Label = c("10", "10.2", "100.1", "100.25", "100.3", "100.45", 
    "100.5", "100.55", "100mls", "101", "101.25", "101.5", "102", 
    "102.5", "103", "103.5", "104", "104.25", "104.5", "105", 
    "105.5", "105.6", "105.75", "106", "106.5", "107", "108", 
    "108.5", "108.8", "109", "109.5", "110", "110.5", "111", 
    "111.5", "111.75", "112", "112.5", "113", "113.5", "114", 
    "114.5", "115", "115.2", "115.5", "116", "116.1", "116.5", 
    "117", "117.5", "118", "118.5", "119", "119.5", "119.7", 
    "12", "12.5", "120", "120.5", "120.6", "121", "121.5", "122", 
    "122.4", "122.5", "123", "123.5", "124", "124.5", "125", 
    "125.5", "126", "126.5", "127", "127.5", "128", "128.5", 
    "129", "129.5", "130", "130.5", "131", "131.5", "132", "132.5", 
    "133", "133.2", "133.5", "134", "134.5", "135", "135.5", 
    "136", "136.5", "137", "137.5", "138", "138.5", "139", "139.5", 
    "14", "140", "140.5", "141", "141.5", "142", "142.5", "143", 
    "143.5", "144", "144.5", "145", "145.5", "146", "146.5", 
    "147", "147.5", "148", "148.5", "149", "149.5", "15", "150", 
    "150.5", "151", "151.5", "152", "152.5", "153", "153.5", 
    "154", "154.5", "155", "155.5", "156", "157", "157.5", "158", 
    "158.5", "159", "159.5", "16", "160", "160.5", "161", "161.5", 
    "162", "162.5", "163", "164", "164.5", "165", "165.5", "166", 
    "166.5", "167", "167.5", "168", "168.5", "169", "169.5", 
    "170", "170.5", "171", "171.5", "172", "172.5", "173", "173.5", 
    "174", "174.5", "175", "175.5", "176.5", "177", "177.5", 
    "178", "178.5", "179", "179.5", "18", "180", "180.5", "181", 
    "181.5", "182", "182.5", "183", "183.5", "184", "184.5", 
    "185", "185.5", "186", "186.5", "187", "187.5", "188", "188.5", 
    "189", "189.5", "190", "190.5", "191", "191.5", "192", "192.5", 
    "193", "193.5", "194", "194.5", "195", "195.5", "196", "196.5", 
    "197", "197.5", "198", "198.5", "199", "199.5", "2", "20", 
    "200", "200.5", "200mls", "201", "201.5", "203", "203.5", 
    "204", "204.5", "205", "206", "206.5", "207", "207.5", "208", 
    "208.5", "209", "209.5", "21", "210", "210.5", "211", "211.5", 
    "212", "212.5", "213", "213.5", "214", "215", "215.5", "216", 
    "216.5", "217", "217.5", "218", "218.5", "219", "219.5", 
    "22", "220", "220.5", "221", "221.5", "222", "222.5", "223", 
    "223.5", "224", "224.5", "225", "225.5", "226", "226.5", 
    "227", "227.5", "228", "229", "229.5", "23", "230", "230.5", 
    "231", "231.5", "232", "232.5", "233", "233.5", "234", "234.5", 
    "235", "235.5", "236", "236.5", "237", "237.5", "238", "238.5", 
    "239", "239.5", "24", "240.5", "241", "241.5", "242", "242.5", 
    "243", "243.5", "244", "244.5", "245", "245.5", "246", "247", 
    "247.5", "248", "248.5", "249", "249.5", "250", "250.5", 
    "251", "251.5", "252", "252.5", "253", "253.5", "254", "254.5", 
    "255", "255.5", "256", "256.5", "257", "257.5", "258", "258.5", 
    "259", "259.5", "26.9", "260", "260.5", "261", "261.5", "262", 
    "262.5", "263", "263.5", "264", "264.5", "265", "265.5", 
    "266", "266.5", "267", "267.5", "268", "268.5", "269", "270", 
    "270.5", "271", "271.5", "272", "272.5", "273", "274.5", 
    "275", "275.5", "276", "277", "277.5", "278.5", "279", "279.5", 
    "280", "280.5", "281", "281.5", "282.5", "284", "284.5", 
    "285", "285.5", "287", "288", "288.5", "289", "289.5", "290", 
    "290.5", "292", "292.5", "293", "294", "295", "296", "299", 
    "3", "30", "300.5", "301", "302.5", "303.5", "304", "304.5", 
    "305.5", "309", "31", "315", "315.5", "316", "317.5", "318", 
    "318.5", "323", "323.5", "329.5", "331.5", "334", "335.5", 
    "337", "337.5", "342", "344.5", "347", "35.75", "353.5", 
    "357", "359", "363.5", "37", "37.7", "38.55", "380.5", "382", 
    "384.5", "39", "39.45", "39.5", "39.85", "391.5", "392.5", 
    "395.5", "397", "4", "40", "406.5", "40ml", "40mls", "41.4", 
    "41.75", "42", "42.5", "42.6", "42.75", "42.9", "43.7", "435", 
    "44.2", "44.25", "44.4", "44.9", "45", "45.05", "45.6", "45.65", 
    "45.75", "46.4", "46.55", "461.5", "47", "47.25", "47.4", 
    "47.8", "48", "48.4", "48.9", "49.2", "49.35", "49.55", "5", 
    "50.1", "50.15", "50.25", "50.3", "50.55", "50.85", "50.95", 
    "51.55", "51.75", "52", "52.05", "52.3", "52.4", "53.35", 
    "53.45", "53.5", "53.55", "53.7", "53.85", "53.95", "54", 
    "54.1", "54.3", "54.45", "54.65", "54.7", "54.75", "54.85", 
    "55", "55.05", "55.5", "55.55", "55.6", "55.65", "55.75", 
    "55.8", "55.85", "55.95", "56", "56.15", "56.3", "56.35", 
    "56.6", "56.65", "57", "57.05", "57.15", "57.2", "57.45", 
    "57.55", "57.7", "57.75", "57.85", "57.95", "58.05", "58.1", 
    "58.35", "58.45", "58.6", "58.75", "59.2", "59.25", "59.3", 
    "59.45", "59.6", "59.7", "59.8", "59.9", "6", "60", "60.3", 
    "60.35", "60.45", "60.5", "60.85", "60.95", "61.2", "61.3", 
    "61.4", "61.55", "61.8", "61.85", "62.35", "62.95", "63.15", 
    "63.65", "63.7", "63.9", "63.95", "64", "64.25", "64.4", 
    "64.7", "64.8", "65", "65.3", "65.5", "65.55", "65.6", "65.7", 
    "65.8", "66.2", "66.35", "66.45", "66.6", "67", "67.05", 
    "67.2", "67.25", "67.3", "67.35", "67.5", "67.65", "67.7", 
    "67.8", "67.85", "67.9", "67.95", "68.1", "68.5", "68.7", 
    "68.9", "68.95", "69.1", "69.15", "69.35", "69.45", "69.55", 
    "69.6", "69.7", "70.15", "70.45", "70.5", "70.65", "70.7", 
    "70.75", "70.8", "70.9", "71.05", "71.1", "71.55", "71.6", 
    "71.7", "71.75", "72.25", "72.6", "72.65", "72.75", "72.85", 
    "72.9", "73.05", "73.3", "73.35", "73.45", "73.55", "73.6", 
    "73.65", "73.75", "73.8", "73.85", "73.95", "74.3", "74.35", 
    "74.45", "74.55", "74.6", "74.7", "74.75", "74.8", "74.95", 
    "75", "75.05", "75.1", "75.15", "75.2", "75.3", "75.4", "75.45", 
    "75.5", "75.55", "75.75", "76.1", "76.15", "76.2", "76.25", 
    "76.35", "76.5", "76.55", "76.7", "76.75", "76.8", "77.15", 
    "77.4", "77.55", "77.65", "77.7", "77.75", "77.85", "77.95", 
    "78.05", "78.1", "78.15", "78.25", "78.3", "78.35", "78.45", 
    "78.6", "78.7", "78.75", "78.85", "78.9", "79", "79.1", "79.15", 
    "79.35", "79.4", "79.6", "79.7", "79.8", "79.9", "8", "80.35", 
    "80.5", "80.55", "80.8", "81", "81.05", "81.25", "81.3", 
    "81.45", "81.65", "81.85", "81.9", "81.95", "82.1", "82.25", 
    "82.5", "82.55", "82.7", "82.75", "83", "83.15", "83.2", 
    "83.55", "83.6", "84", "84.15", "84.4", "84.45", "84.6", 
    "84.65", "84.85", "85.1", "85.15", "85.2", "85.25", "85.35", 
    "85.6", "85.8", "85.9", "85.95", "86.1", "86.15", "86.4", 
    "86.45", "86.7", "86.85", "86.95", "87.35", "87.4", "87.95", 
    "88.05", "88.1", "88.2", "88.7", "88.75", "88.9", "89", "89.1", 
    "89.6", "89.8", "89.85", "90.15", "90.35", "90.4", "90.5", 
    "90.6", "90.9", "91", "91.1", "91.3", "91.35", "91.45", "91.6", 
    "91.8", "92", "92.05", "92.3", "92.4", "92.45", "92.5", "92.7", 
    "92.95", "93", "93.05", "93.2", "93.25", "93.75", "93.9", 
    "94.05", "94.1", "94.15", "94.3", "94.4", "94.5", "94.85", 
    "95.25", "95.8", "95.85", "95.9", "95.95", "96.15", "96.3", 
    "96.4", "96.6", "96.8", "96.85", "97", "97.05", "97.2", "97.5", 
    "97.75", "97.8", "97.95", "98.15", "98.25", "98.35", "98.4", 
    "98.45", "98.55", "98.7", "98.9", "98.95", "99", "99.1", 
    "99.4", "99.5", "99.6", "99.65"), class = "factor"), Sort = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("BG Data", 
    "Carb", "Insulin"), class = "factor"), Order = c(1505L, 1506L, 
    87L, 1507L, 1508L, 1509L, 258L, 1510L, 1511L, 1512L, 1513L, 
    1514L, 88L, 1515L, 1516L, 1517L, 1518L, 1519L, 1520L, 1521L, 
    1522L, 1523L, 1524L, 1525L, 89L, 1526L, 1527L), Subject.ID..bg = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Visitbg = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Datebg = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Startbg = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Endbg = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), BG.Type = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), BG.Data = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("EDC.ID.", 
"Subject.ID..", "Visit", "Data", "Start", "End", "Type", "Amount", 
"Sort", "Order", "Subject.ID..bg", "Visitbg", "Datebg", "Startbg", 
"Endbg", "BG.Type", "BG.Data"), row.names = 1446:1472, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I edited my post. The time on the x-axis are not in chronological order and the amount values on the y-axis are not in ascending order.

Comment: Not a bad first question! In general (for yourself and especially for posting), try to make your example minimal. In this case, the PDF has nothing to do with the plot, so don't bother with that part. And if you share your data by using `dput(carb1)`, then we'll be able to copy/paste the data into R and end up with all the same column classes which is very helpful on both sides and especially important when dates and factors are involved.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Gregor I appreciate the insight! I edited my post and cleaned up the code. I also have a link to a picture so it is easier to visualize. I highlighted the ares of concern in green!  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_5qwBmXKndda3I3ckd0eExUaW8/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @BillyBoy I had a look of your data. Your have `Amount` as factor. You want to change that to `numeric` like this: `carb1$Amount <- as.numeric(carb1$Amount)`. I think this will solve your issue. As for the x axis, you probably need time object. You will need `scale_x_date` or similar kind using `library(scales)`.

Comment: @jazzurro no no no! Convert with `carb1$Amount <- as.numeric(as.character(carb1$Amount))`, other wise you'll just get the factor levels.

Comment: @Gregor thanks for the tip! 'code'(Amount) is now showing up as a numeral but the ordering is still all over the place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use the right classes for your columns:

```
carb1$Amount = as.numeric(as.character(carb1$Amount))
carb1$time = as.POSIXct(carb1$Start, format = "%H:%M", tz = "GMT")

q <- ggplot(data=carb1, aes(x=time, y=Amount, group=Type, color= Type)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    geom_line() +
    theme(text = element_text(size=12), 
          axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, vjust=1))
r <- q + facet_grid(Sort~., scales="free")
r
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an additional approach. You have two things to convert. One is `Amount` and the other is `Start`. In this approach, you will see the time as you specified on x-axis, compared to Gregor's approach. What I did was to add 0 for `9:54` using `sprintf`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

mydf <- mutate(mydf, Start = sprintf("%05s", as.character(Start)),
                     Amount = as.numeric(as.character(Amount)))

ggplot(data = mydf, aes(x = Start, y = Amount, group = Type, colour = Type)) +
geom_point() +
geom_line() +
theme(text = element_text(size=8), 
      axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, vjust=1)) +
facet_grid(Sort ~., scales = "free")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the input @jazzurro! Ill make sure to look into both methods and understand the differences between them.

Comment: @BillyBoy The difference is whether you create a date object with `as.POSIXct` or a character object by adding zero. Hope that will help you. :)